# Настройка nginx на вложенную папку для работы фреймоврка

Tags: nginx, php-nginx

Есть директория на сайте внутри которой развернут фреймворк. Никак не могу нацелить вызовы на index.php фреймворка при вызове по имени директории в url

```
/var/www/admin
  |-/public/
  |--index.php
```

```
Url - http://<ip>/admin/
```

```
    location ~ ^/admin/(.*) {
        index index.php;
        alias /var/www/admin/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

Так же нужно что бы все роуты обрабатывались роутером фреймворка. Т.е. что бы url вида

```
http://<ip>/admin/service/
```

Так же обрабатывался файлом index.php фреймворка из папки puplic

Answer (score 0):

Используйте стандартный подход:

```
location = /admin {
    return 301 /admin/;
}

location /admin/ {
    index index.php;
    root /var/www/admin/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```